# Is Palpatine just lucky that Obi-Wan discovers the clone army and then the Separatist plot, justifying his emergency powers?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

It sure seems like Jango didn't *want* to be tracked since he kills the original assassin sent after Amidala with a dart when she's about to talk, and then he flees as soon as Obi-Wan shows up on Kamino and starts asking him questions, although not without first trying to kill Obi-Wan on the launch pad. Once he realizes Obi-Wan has tracked him to Geonosis he sure seems to try his best to kill him again in the asteroid field (and he says as much to Boba, who I see no reason for him to deceive on this point).

However, the discovery of the clone army and the discovery of the Separatist plot on Geonosis are exactly the two pieces of information that Palpatine needs to get back to Coruscant in order to justify the Galactic Senate granting him emergency powers because:

- He allegedly wants to use the powers to authorize the creation of the Republic Army, and the existence of the clone army on Kamino is what makes that possible
- The immediate threat of the Separatist plot is what he uses to justify the urgent need for the creation of the Republic Army consisting of clones through emergency powers, since "the Senate would never approve the use of clones before the Separatists attack"

**Is Palpatine playing 4-D chess here and this was his master plan all along**, carefully coordinated with Jango to lure Obi-Wan into exactly the discoveries he needed all while making it seem like he wanted to kill him, **or did Palpatine originally have a different plan, and simply jump on this opportunity when it presented itself**?

Comment: Lucky is a very loaded word. Palpatine always  wanted the Republic to use the clone army in the war, Obi-Wan just found it a few months early.

Comment: @Valorum right - he certainly intended to reveal these pieces of information and use them to get emergency powers *at some point*, but what I'm wondering is, is there anything in the canon to suggest that he intended them to be discovered in the way that they were (fortuitously, perhaps, while Amidala was away and he could manipulate Jar Jar into proposing a motion granting him executive powers to create an army despite her stated opposition to the MCA), or was he planning on this happening later and things just worked out better than he could have expected?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that droid armies turning up out of nowhere and occupying key planets would have been enough to encourage the Republic to start clamouring for a solution. Palpatine would then reveal it. Note, though, that Palpatine can also see the future, so who the hell knows what he thought *might* happen.

Comment: Obi-Wan Kenobi: *"In my experience, there's no such thing as luck."* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aZsAlpJB0k

Answer (score 9):

### "Everything that has transpired has done so according to my design."

While there are no definite explicit clues for either *pro or contra*, there is lots of circumstantial evidence pointing out that Palpatine prepared everything that happened. Let us ask ourselves a couple of questions :

#### What is Palpatine's primary objective?

The answer would be fulfillment of the [Sith Grand Plan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Plan) and destruction of The Jedi Order. The Clone Army was essential in this regard - at the opportune moment, the Clones would execute Order 66 and wipe out the Jedi. Of course, the Clone Army had to  first be grown on Kamino, and for that, the location of Kamino was erased from the Jedi Archives. But now as both the Clone Army was created as well as their opponents, the Droid Army, it was time for the Jedi to "discover" them. There was also a possibility that the Kaminoans offer unsolicited help to the Republic, but that would raise much more suspicion. Instead, it was arranged that supposedly-clumsy Jango Fett (in fact [**the best**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jango_Fett) bounty hunter at that time) outsource his job to an underling, and then kill that underling with nothing else but a dart made exclusively on Kamino. And speaking of botched assassination attempt:

#### What is Palpatine's secondary objective?

Well of course to turn Anakin Skywalker, Chosen One of the Force, to the Dark Side and make him his Sith apprentice. In order to do that Palpatine plays with his emotions and his attachments. Palpatine clearly senses Anakin's attraction to Padme. In fact, right after the first failed assassination attempt, it was he that orders Kenobi and Anakin to guard her, conveniently setting the two of them together and alone when Kenobi leaves to pursue the Kamino connection.

In fact, throughout the prequels, Padme Amidala is Palpatine's most crucial asset. Not only is she Anakin's biggest weakness, Palpatine skillfully uses her to get rid of the previous Chancellor, Valorum. Later, as young, charismatic and idealistic (but unfortunately not very bright) Senator, she leads a pro-peace faction. Palpatine skillfully allows her some success (initiative for talks with CIS , reduction in military spending etc ...) . But then, through his control of the Separatists, smacks down those efforts with their renewed aggression, leading to his supposedly reluctant acceptance of more power and tighter military measures. Therefore it is obvious he does not want her dead (otherwise Fett would make short work of her) and possibly a martyr. Instead, he skillfully toys with her, and sets her up to be where he wants her to be .

Answer (score 3):

While it is not possible to give a definitive answer **Is Palpatine playing 4-D chess here and this was his master plan all along** is far more likely.

Let's consider the events that lead Obi Wan to the clone army.

1. A botched assassination attempt on Senator Amidala takes place.
2. The assassin is killed by Jango Fett.
3. Obi Wan finds the dart that killed the assassin.
4. Obi Wan tracks the dart to Kamino.

Note that Jango Fett acted on the orders of Count Dooku, which received his orders from Palpatine. As you can see, steps 1 and 3 could be easily avoided if Palpatine did not want the Jedi order track the clone army.

Speculating the extremely meaningless way to kill Amidala (why not just blast her with a drone as soon as you got in or shoot her with a Kamino dart directly?) was to ensure Amidala would not die, I reach this conjecture:

Palpatine wanted to botch the Amidala assassination, so he wanted the assassination attempt to be carried out with an inefficient way. He also provided Jango (via Count Dooku) with the Kamino dart and ordered him to kill Zam Wesell. Similarly, he could have counted on Jango using Kamino dart, just because Kamino was already removed from Jedi maps and it was an effective weapon.

Regardless, it makes more sense for the story line to believe that Palpatine planned it all along.

Comment: I've seen I've seen people pushing this whole "*botched assassination was deliberate*" theory before, but it's been [comprehensively debunked.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156672/20774)

Comment: @Valorum I am sure it is. Regardless, even if you remove all "botched" from my answer, the core remains the same.

Comment: Palpatine may well have seen events play out through prediction of the future, but Dooku certainly didn't expect the Clone army to arrive when it did and nearly got the entire leadership of the Separatist Alliance caught or killed. It's hard to imagine that Palpatine would have risked that *intentionally*

Comment: I'm with @Valorum on this one. It also seems pretty clear that even if (and that's a big if) Palpatine wanted the dart to be traced to Kamino, Jango definitely didn't want Obi-Wan following him to Geonosis since he very clearly tried to kill him in the asteroid field and said as much to Boba, who he had no reason to deceive.

Comment: While Palpatine got unscathed from the Battle of Geonosis, Dooku lost his credibility. Besides, in Battle of Geonosis, more than a hundred (179 according to wiki) Jedi died. Since the only reason for Palpatine to fuel the war between the Senate and the separatists was to destroy Jedi order, tell me again who risked what?

Comment: Well, if the Jedi had been more aggressive, they would have blasted the base ships from orbit. That would have decapitated the Separatists in one single strike and ended the entire Clone War.

Comment: And risk even more systems join the Separatist alliance? In case of a 1956 Budapest kind of attack, even more systems would join the alliance. Besides, the Droid army was not created only in Geonosis and Trade Federation had already a sizeable army. Finally, you can't decapitate Separatists without destroying the Trade Federation. Come on, use some political science to analyse the decisions of the Jedi, Senate and Palpatine.

Comment: @Valorum In your vocabulary, is completely debunked mean "answered by myself"? You even question the weapon of choice for the assassination in the linked answer. How does this prove my answer is sub par?

Comment: @C.Koca - Debunked as in, reliable (canon) sources confirm that it's not the case. Which basically leaves people's headcanon as the only thing that's still propping it up

Comment: I guess you linked the wrong answer. It doesn't say anything about debunking.

Comment: Reasonable answer, add to that that Palpatine basically set up Anakin and Padme to be together in Episode II , sensing that she could be his weakness leading him from the path of Jedi . Also, Jedi had to discover Clones in order to be eventually killed by them .

Comment: @airshanemode, if you assume Palpatine wanted the Jedi to get to Geonosis, then Fett trying to kill Obi-wan still makes sense: if he kills Obi-wan, you've got a Jedi who is killed/vanishes at Geonosis, which would draw the attention of the other Jedi. If he doesn't manage to kill Obi-wan, you've got him investigating Geonosis which will inevitably result in him calling in the other Jedi. in both cases, you've got Jedi going to Geonosis. Getting Obi-wan there is primary; what happens after to him is irrelevant.